# Vulnerabilities for Red Team assessment

Tags: penetration-test, windows-10

I'm working on my dissertation for my bachelor's degree. I'm trying to create a framework which would make it possible to launch an entire virtual infrastructure, this would then be used to simulate a Red/Blue team assessment. I'm getting close to being finished, but need some vulnerabilities to implement for one of my scenarios. The current environment currently consists of 4 workstations (windows 10), 1 domain controller (server 2016), 1 file server (Server 2016 core) and a mail and web server (Linux).

Its relatively easy to find some basic vulnerabilities, but I rather implement something that would be consistent with a real-world scenario. Any of you have any tips on what vulnerabilities I could implement?

Comment: I think this question is overly broad and not a great fit for the format here. There are a number of courses teaching Red Team methodology which should give you an idea of things to focus on for your lab such as AD misconfigurations, etc.

Answer (score 2):

By implementing, I am assuming you mean one of the following:

1) **Developing** a vulnerable application yourself and then deploying it to one of your servers.

2) Taking an **existing piece of software** (likely an older release) that is vulnerable to certain attack. Perferrably, for learning purposes, the deployed software will already have common vulnerabilities that have been publicly disclosed on the Internet.

Here are some examples of common vulnerabilities you may find in real-world software deployments that may be within your scope:

- **Denial of service** vulnerabilities via a buffer overflow in a C/C++ applications.
- **Directory traversal** vulnerabilities in misconfigured web servers.
- **Code injection** vulnerabilities in web applications.
- **Integer overflow** vulnerabilities in C/C++ applications.
- **Information disclosure** vulnerabilities in any sort of application.
- The list goes on...

Whether you want to develop your own software or use something that already exists is up to you.

Overall though, I feel like this is a very broad topic, but I think one of the best ways for learning more about software vulnerabilities is by reading existing [bug bounty](https://hackerone.com/hacktivity) reports and technical details found in [CVEs](https://www.cvedetails.com/).